# ASP:Checkbox oncheckedchanged pop up confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert

I would love to get a pop up alert asking the user "Do you wish to change the state of this event?" when the user checks a box in a list. This is what I have so far. Any ideas?

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ActiveDisabled" HeaderText="Status" AllowFiltering="false">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="isChecked" Checked='<%# Eval("active") %>' AutoPostBack="true"
        OnCheckedChanged="CheckChanged" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor='<%# (bool)Eval("active") ? System.Drawing.Color.Green : System.Drawing.Color.Red %>'
        Text='<%# string.Format("{0}", (bool)Eval("active") ? "Active" : "In-Active") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hidd_ID" Text='<%# Eval("categoryID") %>' Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="hidd_eventID" Text='<%# Eval("eventID") %>' Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have tried a few things but I honestly can't seem to get this working. The function is calls "CheckChanged" looks like this

```
protected void CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem row = (GridDataItem)(((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    Label tmpLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("hidd_ID");
    Label hidd_eventID = (Label)row.FindControl("hidd_eventID");
    int eventCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(tmpLabel.Text);
    int eventId = Convert.ToInt32(hidd_eventID.Text);
    ActiveUtility(eventCategoryId, eventId);
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to use jQuery to add an onclick event to the CheckBox.

Comment: Hmm thanks for that looking into it now. Haven't done that before so I am looking for a good example. Thanks.

Comment: Would something like this work?

`$('#isChecked').mousedown(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        this.checked = confirm("Are you sure you want to change the state?");
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
});`

I never really touched Jquery at all lol, but I am learning slowly.